# how to fix account is not eligible for google now on galaxy note 4 running Android KitKat?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, google-account, google-now

I just bought a new samsung galaxy note 4, I want to to use the google now card, but when I sign in with my account to opt-in to use it, I get a message said: "This account is not eligible for google now". Can you tell me what's wrong with my account? and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this from [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/nexus/fCe24Oqj-Jw/9Q2jPjAy5IkJ)

1) log into Google Apps dashboard (https://admin.google.com) as admin;

2) once logged in, at the bottom of the page you should see 'More controls', by clicking it choose 'Other Google services';

3) once in other Google services click on the top right 'Filter' icon and uncheck 'Show top featured services';

4) find service called 'Location history' and enable it (I did for all users);

Now, part on the website is done; go back to your phone and do:
Note! it may take a couple of minutes for the changes from website to be visible on your phone (on my was rather instant);

1) Settings > Accounts (Google) > Location > Google Location Reporting and enable both options;

2) Go to Google Settings (accessible from All apps) and then to Search & Now and then to Accounts and privacy;

3) Click on item called Google Account (first one) and LOG OUT;

4) repeat phone steps 1-3 but now (re)enable account.

Now you should be asked if you wish to use Google Now

Comment: I can't log into Google Apps dashboard

Comment: what error you got when you login to Google Apps dashboard? your device is connected to internet?

Comment: It's connected to internet. When I try to log in with my normal gmail account, it redirect me to log in page every time.